# Removing and redirecting part of url using .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm trying to remove part of the URL on my server using .htaccess. Say that I have this folder structure.

root:

- official (codeigniter)
- program (wordpress)
- .htaccess

/official is my main folder when accessing the root domain (`www.example.com/official`). I wanted to remove `/official` from my URL, and I kinda already did that with this .htaccess script.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^$ official/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((?!official/).+)$ official/$1 [L,NC]
```

The problem with this script is while I can access the ci project without `/official`, I still can access them with the `/official`. What I wanted is  removing `/official` entirely or redirecting it so that the URL only displays the root domain.

My CI .htaccess is this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I actually solved this by redirecting through CI index.php. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please see: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new folder
2. build another index.php
3. redirect the .htaccess to new index.php(no.2) inside the new folder(no.1)
4. change the files dir in htaccess below

   ```
    # Disable directory browsing
    Options All -Indexes

    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Rewrite engine
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    # Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and features.
    # FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        RewriteEngine On

        # If you installed CodeIgniter in a subfolder, you will need to
        # change the following line to match the subfolder you need.
        # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
        # RewriteBase /

        # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
          RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

        # Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

        # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
        # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
        # request to the front controller, index.php
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ dir/index.php/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

        # Ensure Authorization header is passed along
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
        RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
        # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
        # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
        ErrorDocument 404 index.php
    </IfModule>

    # Disable server signature start
        ServerSignature Off
    # Disable server signature end

    # Disable directory browsing
    Options All -Indexes
   ```
5. index.php

> ```
> <?php
> ini_set('display_errors', 1);
> ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
> error_reporting(E_ALL);
> require '../codeigniter/public/index.php';
> ?>
> ```

6. directory tag (not recommended)

> ```
> <Directory "/var/www/html">
>   AllowOverride AuthConfig
>   Order allow,deny
>   Allow from all
> </Directory>
> ```

Comment: I'm still not following, what's the new folder for? And where do i have to put the directory tag?

Comment: the directory will deny all access to your another folder as you mentioned official folder any access will directly to new index.php, inside the index.php put a require tag function to your codeigniter public/index.php

Comment: any folder will able to access if it is in your root/document directory like https://example.com/codeigniter/app/config/database.php a brute force like dirbuster can find your folder

Comment: what's the final file structure would be?

Comment: 3 folders, 1 htaccess. If you couldn't understand this answer. then, I will delete it.

Comment: I'm sorry but i still don't quite understand.

Comment: maybe a few test will make you understand

Comment: Where should i put the .htaccess in point 4? is it to replace my old .htaccess in root folder? or put it in the new folder?